# Splitting Boost.Spirit.X3 parsers into several TUs

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3, translation-unit

I'm struggling with Boost.Spirit.X3 again.

I have several logical groups of parsers (statements, expressions, etc.), each of which is represented by several files:

- `group.hpp` - contains `typedef`s, `BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE` and `extern` variable declaration for those parsers that are used "outside"
- `group_def.hpp` - includes the previous one and contains actual definitions of parsers, `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`, etc.
- `group.cpp` - includes the previous one and contains explicit template instantiations (via `BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE`)

Basically, it more or less follows the structure proposed in the official [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/tutorials.html). The only difference is that my grammar is much more complicated so I'm trying to split it into several translation units. All these TUs are then compiled into one library which, in turn, is linked then to the main executable.

**I've tried to make a "minimal" example [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G5AfxTiMP2uRdawq)** (live on Wandbox) as it would be inconvenient to list all the files here.
**It doesn't work though** because of some unresolved externals, so, most probably, I instantiate something incorrectly, but I've already spent about a week for this, so I'm quite desperate and don't feel like I'm able to handle this on my own.

A few questions and answers:

#### Why do I prefer using three files per "group"?

First, because I tried to make it in such a way that I don't want to recompile everything on any small change (not sure if I succeeded in this), so the idea is that `somegroup.hpp` is just a "lightweight" header with declarations, `somegroup_def.hpp` is a header with definitions, and `somegroup.cpp` is just used in order to create a translation unit.

Second, I split `_def.hpp` and `.cpp` because I also include these `_def.hpp`-files directly to tests where I cover not only `extern` parsers but also "internal" auxiliary ones.

#### Why am I using `extern` variables?

I tried it also with functions that return parsers instead (similar to how it is done in the tutorial). Basically, this is the way how it is implemented and does work now. I don't like it because, for instance, given a parser `lang::parser::import`, I have to either give a function another name (`lang::parser::import_`) or place it within another namespace (i.e. `lang::import`). Also, I like the way to use parsers directly how it is done in the Spirit itself (i.e. without parentheses: `import` vs `import_()`).

### My actual questions are the following:

- How to properly organize the structure if I want to spread my parsers over several translation units?
- And what exactly am I missing in the example of code above, so that it doesn't link?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Apparently, no one knows how to do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ## Why do I prefer using three files per "group"?

I am, myself, find separation into `grammar_def.hpp` and `grammar.cpp` useless, but that is just an opinion.

> ## Why am I using extern variables?
>
> I tried it also with functions that return parsers instead

Do not do this. It will lead to static initialization order fiasco. Rule placeholders are lightweight enough to instantiate them in every translation unit.

> How to properly organize the structure if I want to spread my parsers over several translation units?

That is a question about tastes. All you need is to instantiate a rule in one of the TU and have a `x3::rule<...>`+`BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE` in every other that uses it.

The best way to achieve that is to split `x3::rule<...>` off `.cpp`/`_def.hpp` into separate header (place it into your "lightweight" `.hpp`), and include it in every TU that needs those rules.

See https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/pull/4072/files and https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/pull/493/files

> And what exactly am I missing in the example of code above, so that it doesn't link?

1. You are mixing `std::string::const_iterator` and `std::string::iterator` iterators.
2. You are using some of your skippers as parsers (f.ex. `document_def = eols >> +megarule >> eols`) but do not instantiate them with a proper context. Either simply do not make them rules or add `BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE` with a context that you see in the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I played with various ways of doing it a little bit longer. I think it's really not worth it to have such a complicated separation at all because it's mostly meaningless.